# LINQ how to use "group by" to simplify lists with duplicate attributes

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object "ChartObject" and I want to group certain fields together before I can plot the whole list.

```
public class ChartObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public long Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I want to group the Type for each Year to prevent duplicate types for each year. For each type I want the summed cost under that year.

For example this list:
ChartObject(Type1, 2015, $10)
ChartObject(Type1, 2015, $20)
ChartObject(Type2, 2016, $10)
ChartObject(Type1, 2016, $10)
ChartObject(Type2, 2017, $10)
ChartObject(Type2, 2017, $10)

Should be combined to this:
ChartObject(Type1, 2015, $30)
ChartObject(Type1, 2016, $10)
ChartObject(Type2, 2016, $10)
ChartObject(Type2, 2017, $20)

This is my LINQ query I have so far. It is not correct since it doesn't also group by the year:

```
List<ChartObject> coList = GetItems();

var query =
(
    from l in coList
    group l by l.Type into X
    select new ChartObject()
    {
        Cost = X.Sum(c => c.Cost),
        Type = X.First().Type,
        Year = X.First().Year,
    }

).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general approach is as follows:

```
// First GroupBy compound type
.GroupBy(i => new { i.Type, i.Year })

// Then select from the Group Key and
// apply an Aggregate/query on the Grouped Values
.Select(g => new {
   Type = g.Key.Type,         // Pull out key values
   Year = g.Key.Year,
   Cost = g.Sum(i => i.Cost)  // Sum all items in group
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It returns the same number of items in the list. Does it actually modify the list I'm grouping by? I tried your solution by doing "coList.GroupBy(...).Select(...)"

Comment: @AC IEnumerable methods always return a *new* sequence (or query for an IQueryable). You have to assign it back to a variable (probably after a ToList call).

Comment: I see. Thank you, it worked perfectly when I assigned it to a new list.